# Convergence of empirical distribution parameters of a sequence of generated normal variables

Tags: normal-distribution, convergence

I am generating a sequence of normal random variables (using the routines from boost C++ library). How fast would you expect the mean and the variance of the sequence converge to the actual variance?

In my case the true values are:

```
mean=-0.01208333333333333
variance=0.0075
```

For `10000000` generated variables I get:

```
Mean=-0.0120757, 
var=0.00750125
```

which intuitively seem quite far (especially variance) for this ridiculously large number of samples. Should I expect faster convergence (i.e. there is some issue with my code), or is it what you would expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your results are well within expectations. The random variable defined by $(n-1)s^2 \over \sigma^2$ is a $\chi^2$ random variable with variance of $2(n-1)$. Using this I find the standard deviation of $s$ to be 0.000003354, which when compared to your observed difference of 0.00000125 means this is not unusual. A similar argument shows your $\bar x$ result is also in line.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this in Stata (actually Mata) I got the following results for 10 such large samples (first column is the mean, the second is the variance):

```
: res = J(10,2,.)

: for(i=1; i <= 10; i++) {
>         x = rnormal(10000000,1, -0.01208333333333333, sqrt(0.0075))
>         res[i,.] = meanvariance(x)'
> }

: res
                   1              2
     +-------------------------------+
   1 |  -.0120843169    .0075019019  |
   2 |  -.0121035264    .0074968712  |
   3 |  -.0120866703    .0074955339  |
   4 |  -.0120646992     .007499407  |
   5 |  -.0120959452    .0074969704  |
   6 |  -.0120737802    .0075110002  |
   7 |  -.0120411955    .0074920638  |
   8 |  -.0120973025    .0075073199  |
   9 |  -.0120785954     .007501123  |
  10 |   -.012116408    .0075042688  |
     +-------------------------------+
```

So your results seem to be in line with what happens inside Stata. That is no guarantee that there is no error, but it is still somewhat reassuring.

---

**Edit:**

I checked the variances from Stata's random normal number generators against the results mentioned in soakly's answer and not surprisingly it performs very well:

```
clear all

local n = 1000
local reps = 10000
local m = -0.01208333333333333
local v = .0075

set obs `reps'

mata
res = J(`reps',2,.)

for(i=1; i <= `reps'; i++) {
    x = rnormal(`n',1, `m', sqrt(`v'))
    res[i,.] = meanvariance(x)'
}

idx =st_addvar("double","v")
st_store(.,idx,res[.,2])

end

gen chi = (`n'-1)*v/`v'
qchi chi, df(`=`n'-1')
```

[image]